# How can I have multiple authorized_keys files?

Tags: ssh

I want to be able to specify the keys in 2 separate files, one user controlled, the other auto generated by a tool.

How can I make it so that a file like `~/.ssh/authorized_keys_generated` also gets checked for keys on login?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply append the name of the file next to the old one.

`AuthorizedKeysFile     ~/.ssh/authorized_keys ~/.ssh/authorized_keys_generated`

Comment: For what it is worth, the default already contains two files: `.ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2`.

Comment: In one sshd config I've seen this:

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.

so I wouldn't rely on that authorized_keys2 to be an alternative to authorized_keys

Comment: As of "OpenSSH_9.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022" official man page still states that: 'The default is ".ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2''

Answer (score 3):

This not exactly your question, but you also could use [`AuthorizedKeysCommand`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiW_cbKvcj6AhWhx4UKHXWwDBUQFnoECAkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fman.openbsd.org%2Fsshd_config&usg=AOvVaw10zABcy1CyzApV0FhscAln) in ssh config file. `sshd` will launch the command with the user as the first parameter and the stdout of the script should be a string matching `authorized_keys` format.

You could use a script like :

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /home/$1/.ssh/*.pub; do
   cat $file;
done
```

That echos all file in public key in `~/.ssh`, granting access to every key in it.

But there is more to it, `AuthorizedKeysCommand` could be use to call a authorization server that grants access based on your business logic, for instance. It's a powerful tool.